# toSpliced() method throwing TypeError in VS Code Debug Console

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting the following error on VS Code Debug Console;

"Uncaught TypeError TypeError: months.toSpliced is not a function"

when I run this code;

```
const months = ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "May"];

// Inserting an element at index 1
const months2 = months.toSpliced(1, 0, "Feb");
console.log(months2); // ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
```

It is not even my code, I copy-pasted it from here; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced

I came across this error while trying to learn toSpliced() method.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility table at the end of that page? Are you using a new enough version of node.js?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar It was the version of my node. But, I went for the **splice** method instead.

Answer (score 13):

`Array.prototype.toSpliced()` is relatively new feature of node.js, not part of the ECMAScript standard. Even Chrome has these methods available only since version 110 and node only since version 20.0.0 (you can check your currently installed node version prompting `node -v` in your terminal).

If you encaunter problems with this, you could try to replace your code with this:

```
const months = ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "May"];

// Inserting an element at index 1
const months2 = months.slice(); // create a copy of the array
months2.splice(1, 0, "Feb");

console.log(months);   // ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
console.log(months2);  // ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
```

The difference between `splice` method and `toSpliced` is that `splice` modify the original array, while `toSpliced` returns a new array with the specified elements removed, leaving the original array unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Indeed, the problem was my node version. 
But, I didn't update my node, instead I used **splice** method as you suggested. I just had to think harder about my problem. :)

Comment: It might be new, but it is part of the standard now it looks like: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tospliced

I think it was added in ECMAScript 2023

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Array.prototype.toSpliced()` your ECMAScript version has to be ES2023, try changing 'lib' inside of your tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json to include ES2023. It should look something like this:

```
"lib": [
  "ES2023",
]
```

In case you don't have a jsconfig.json you can easily create that using shortcut in VS Code `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and typing `JavaScript: Go to Project Configuration` this will automatically suggest to create one. Inside of that configuration file, you need to add the `lib` option that I mentioned above